# render PDF with annotation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I am developing a web application which is written in php/javascrit and jquery part of the developed application is to render a PDF, the code to load and render the pdf is written in an individual js file called pdfreader.js and the pdf.js file is included as a library.

Now I am trying to allow the user to add annotation to the pdf by clicking on a button afterword a text should appeared and then he can start adding the annotation at any part of the page, then he can the PDF to his computer. the problem that I do not know how to make a connection between the button and the text to show the textarea once the user click on the add annotation button.

HTML code

```
<button class="annotComment" style="float:left">Add Annotation</button>
<input id="fileInput" type="file" name="pdf_file"/>
<div class="separator"></div>
```

javascript

```
WEBSOCKETPDFREADER.getAnnotation = function(contentid){
 if (pageNumber >= 1) 
  return;
 var points = [];
 $("#com_pdf_viewer").click(function(e) {
    if ($("textarea.annotComment").length == 0) {
        var that = this;
        var txt = $("<textarea class='annotComment'></textarea>").css({ top: e.pageY,
         left: e.pageX }).blur(function() { $(this).remove(); }).keypress(function(e2)   
           {
            if (e2.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
                var that2 = this;
                $("#com_pdf_viewer").append($("<div 
                 class='annotComment'>").html(that2.value.replace(/\r/gi, "
                 <br>")).css({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX }));
                $(this).remove();
                points.push({ "x": e.pageX, "y": e.pageY, "text": that2.value })
                $("#results").append('{ "x": ' + e.pageX + ', "y": ' + e.pageY + ', 
                "text": "' + that2.value + '" }<br/>');
            }
        });
        $(this).append(txt);
        txt.each(function() { this.focus(); })
    }
}); 

 WEBSOCKETPDFREADER.send(pageNum,contentid,AllactiveModulesPDFReader[contentid]    
 ['userID'],'setPage',contentid);

  WEBSOCKETPDFREADER.renderPage(pageNum);    

}
```

Do I in the right way or should I change the code or is there is any other library that can be used to add the annotations. Are there any suggestion to solve the problem?! thanks in advance for help ..

Regards,
Rose

Comment: Did you try annotatejs? http://annotatorjs.org/ for annotating pdf.js